# R readr function for previewing csv

Tags: r, csv, dplyr, readr

I am looking for a function or workaround in readr or R base to **"preview" the column types that read_csv will guess before actually importing the data**.
I am working with several files about 60Mb size containing 51 columns and 160k rows so that would make it much easier to build the col_types specification for read_csv.

My excuses if it sounds like an obvious question. I found no answers in the forum to this specific issue and have only recently starting using dplyr. Thanks.

Comment: You could reduce the site of your data with the parameter n_max. However, this might give you different col_types than with the full data. Assume you are only reading the first 100 rows and you have a variable with missings in the first 200 rows and then only characters or numbers. In that case it will guess the col type as logical. So the safewt wac is to read in your full data. You might also want to check the guess_max parameter.

Comment: @deschen thank you for the tips. What you are saying is precisely one of the issues I have encountered: integer columns being guessed as logical because of no data in the first 1000 rows. Will take a look at guess_max and n_max, I have not used these yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went into the readr code and tried to do some surgery to use the read_csv function code but only as far as the spec is guessed.

```
getReaderSpec <- function (file, col_names = TRUE, col_types = NULL, locale = default_locale(), 
                           na = c("", "NA"), quoted_na = TRUE, quote = "\"", 
                           comment = "", trim_ws = TRUE, skip = 0, n_max = Inf, 
                           guess_max = min(1000, n_max), progress = show_progress(), 
                           skip_empty_rows = TRUE) 
{
  tokenizer <- readr:::tokenizer_csv(na = na, quoted_na = quoted_na, 
                             quote = quote, comment = comment, trim_ws = trim_ws, 
                             skip_empty_rows = skip_empty_rows)
  name <- readr:::source_name(file)
  file <- readr:::standardise_path(file)
  if (readr:::is.connection(file)) {
    data <- readr:::datasource_connection(file, skip, skip_empty_rows, 
                                  comment)
    if (readr:::empty_file(data[[1]])) {
      return(tibble::tibble())
    }
  }
  else {
    if (!isTRUE(grepl("\n", file)[[1]]) && readr:::empty_file(file)) {
      return(tibble::tibble())
    }
    if (is.character(file) && identical(locale$encoding, 
                                        "UTF-8")) {
      data <- enc2utf8(file)
    }
    else {
      data <- file
    }
  }
  spec <- readr:::col_spec_standardise(data, skip = skip, skip_empty_rows = skip_empty_rows, 
                               comment = comment, guess_max = guess_max, col_names = col_names, 
                               col_types = col_types, tokenizer = tokenizer, locale = locale)
  readr:::show_cols_spec(spec)
  invisible(spec)
}

myspec <- getReaderSpec("someexample.csv")
```

Comment: Nir, I followed your logic and found the answer: the collection of "spec" functions in readr.  The output of spec_csv is precisely the list of coltypes that read_csv will guess. Many thanks!